# How to retrieve datas from access Database to Datagridview

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have datas as unitprice with 10 decimal places in access database.
I want those decimal places to reduce when it comes to datagridview(round to 2 places).
How can i achieve this. Any idea.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could round it when retrieving it, but I would recommend to round only the displayed value (because you might need the original value for some calculus).

So here is how you format the first column to round to 2:

`grid.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D2";`

Comment: Your code remains the same.No change
dvgproductlist.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = dt.Rows[i]["UnitIncCustom"].ToString();  This how the code retrieve datas from access to gridview